# Adding captured image to next view Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, capture

I'm using *AVFoundation* for capturing. And I want to add captured image to next view's UIImageView. I have a code, that lets me to add one photo to one UIImageView:

```
    func saveToCamera() {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in
            if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer) {

                if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cameraImage, nil, nil, nil)
                    self.scan = cameraImage //recording captured image to variable
                }

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Prepare for segue code:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "MainSegue"){
        let yourNextViewController = (segue.destination as! MainView)
        yourNextViewController.scan = scan
        }            
    }
}
```

Next view:

```
var scan: UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var imgScan: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imgScan.image = scan
}
```

It is primitive and works perfectly, but only for one image. But I want to make up to six photos and add them to six ImageViews. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the key thing here will be to change this:

```
var scan: UIImage!
```

to this:

```
var scan: [UIImage] = []()
```

Now you've got an array you can `append` to, adding each of your images in `prepare`. Of course you will also have to change the code in the second view controller to look at how many images you've got and assign them to your various image views, but that's a trivial change to make.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's pretty simple and I don't know why I don't solve it by myself.

Comment: You can simplify this even further if your image view outlet is an _outlet collection_. This means it is an _array_ of image views. So you have an array of images and an array of image views, which makes assigning each image to its view very easy!